# Delete other Commits from my Pull Request

Tags: git, branch, pull-request

Question to best Practice. I opened a new branch (feature-B) from a feature branch (feature-A). After I finished working on the new branch, I committed and pushed my changes (--set-upstream) Then I set the PR.

We use Bitbucket. And I see in Bitbucket UI that I have the commit from the Branch feature-A in my PullRequest.

What is the best / most elegant way to delete the commit from feature-A from my PR? Do I have to delete it at all, since I can also wait until the other PR (from feature-A) has been memoed.

Comment: What's the PR against? I mean, You're creating a PR of feature B branch to be merged with what exactly?

Comment: @joker the PR against integration. The PR from feature-A is not yet marged with integration.

Comment: OK Gotcha. Let me explain what happens there in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you've made a very small change on `B`, then just create a new branch off the proper source branch, make your changes and go.
2. If you've made a lot of changes in `B`, you can revert the change from `feature-A` in your branch, but then `feature-A` will just put it back.
3. If `feature-A` has a lot of changes and `B` has a lot of changes, create a new branch `feature-C` from the main source branch (e.g. `develop`) and then [cherry pick](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/cherry-pick) your changes from `feature-B` into `C`. That should give you a "clean" set of your own changes that can be merged to `develop` without the changes that sourced in `feature-A`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you think about deleting the branch and creating a new one? So the following workflow:
1. git checkout master
2. git branch -d feature-B
3. git checkout -b feature-B
4. add my changes (only two lines of code added)
5. git push -f

Would this also be a valid solution?

Comment: If it's that small, then sure. Just create a new branch and make the changes there. Updated my answer to reflect three use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting feature A branch won't make a difference. Let's see what's going on here. Please consider the following diagram.

```
          master
            |
C1 <- C2 <- C3    featureA
             \      |
              C4 <- C5
                     \
                      C6 <- C7
                             |
                            featureB
```

Let's first get to an agreement as what a branch in git is. A branch in git is a reference to a commit. A branch is NOT a chain of commits. So, `master` is, from the figure above, a reference to commit `C3`. We don't say `C6` and `C7` are branch `featureB`. We say `featureB` references `C7`.

A commit is said to belong to a branch if it's reachable from the branch commit. `C6` is reachable (as you can see by the arrows). In git, every commit points to the previous one, which is called parent commit. So, `C2` is parent to `C3`. Exception to this is: the initial commit `C1` which doesn't have any parents, and a merge commit, which has two parents.

Now, back to the original question, when you create a PR of `featureB` against `master` (or the integration branch), git sees the changes between `master` and `featureB` include the commits `C4` through, including, `C7`. If you delete a branch, you just delete the reference to the commit, you don't delete the commit. Let's see how the repo looks like after deleting the branch:

```
          master
            |
C1 <- C2 <- C3    
             \      
              C4 <- C5
                     \
                      C6 <- C7
                             |
                            featureB
```

As you can see, the branch, which is merely a pointer to a commit, go deleted. So, still, git will see the changes between `master` and `featureB` involves the commits `C4` through, including, `C7`.

This answers your question as why you see commits from `featureA` and why deleting `featureA` won't help.